# Manejo de html, css, js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen dia amigos, quiero saber como mostrar el contenido de un bloque de codigo que esta con la etiqueta div en una pagina html, que se muestre en otra pagina sin volver a escribir el codigo.

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, numquam!</p>
    <h2>titulo</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
</div>
```

Este codigo, que esta en una pagina, mostrarlo en otra pagina sin volver a escribir el codigo.
Gracias.

Comment: Abre una nueva página y como contenido pon eso

Comment: Una solución compleja pero muy efectiva sería que aprendas a usar un framework SPA como Angular, Vue o React. Esos frameworks están pensados para encerrar cada HTML en "componentes" y luego poder reciclarlos sin la necesidad de volverlos a escribir.

Answer (score 1):

Hola si solo deseas mostrar ese div en otra página podría utilizar algo cómo.
pagina2.html

```
 <div id="repeat"> </div>
    
    <script>
          repeat.display = block; 
    </script>
```